# Sorting the values of linked list and printing them

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a list:

```cpp
struct node
{
    string name;
    int value;
    node* next;
};
```

For example, I save 5 elements to it.

Now I want to find the three greatest elements.

```cpp
node* help = head;

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    node* help2 = head;
    while (help->next)
    {   
        if (help->next->value > help->value)
        {
            help2 = help->next;
        }
        help = help->next;
    }
    cout << help2->name;    
}
```

Thanks to that, I can find the greatest number and show the name of it. But I don't know how I can find the second and third elements and show them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting Linked List C++ with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579587/sorting-linked-list-c-with-pointers)

Comment: Remember the top three results. When you find a number larger than one of the stored values, shift it down one slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know sorting refer this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/ to better understand the concept and types of sorting algorithms.
In this example we have used bubble sort algorithm to sort elements in descending order
//sort your linked list this way as you said you have 5 element in your linked list

```
 //n=5          i. e  size of linked list
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)//sorting logic for linked list to be in descending order
{
    temp=head;
    for(int j=0;j<n-1-i;j++)
    {
        if(temp->value<temp->next->value)
        {
            val=temp->value; //val is integer variable
            nm=temp->name; //nm is string variable
            temp->value=temp->next->value;
            temp->name=temp->next->name;
            temp->next->value=val;
            temp->next->name=nm;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
temp=head;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)// prints 3 elements as you want 3 greatest numbers
{
    cout<<temp->value<<endl;
    cout<<temp->name<<endl;
    temp=temp->next;
    
}
```

Comment: If you have any doubt in code you can ask me, I'll clear your doubt